# Inserting one end of a hose into the other end of the hose.

Tags: general-topology

How far can the one end of a hose be inserted into the other end of the same hose? Assume the hose has infinite flexibility.

Comment: I don't think this question is quite mathematically precise.

Answer (score 3):

Limitlessly.

Just sketch it. In two dimensions, it looks like two spirals going in different directions, the first enclosing the second.

[image: Ouroboros sketched as two spirals]

Comment: This seems to be the intuitive answer, at least in my opinion.